# How to export logo to be used in Word

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, png

I have finished my artwork in Illustrator. It is a logo for my company. It is a horizontal rectangle. I am ready for exporting it so I can use it as part of the header in my Word template. I have got some questions to the process.

Currently the document is 512 x 512 points. However the logo is a rectangular shape, it is placed in the center. Should I create another document with the exact dimensions of the shape so there are no space on the sides before exporting?

And should I export it as a PDF and use that in the Word template? Or as PNG?

I tried exporting the logo as a 512 x 512 point PDF (with no background) but when I open it in Word it shows with the spaces on the side. So how would I deal with this the correct way?

Comment: If you have access to Illustrator, don't you have access to InDesign? If so, I would highly suggest using that instead of Word to lay out your documents. That way you can link directly to your Illustrator artwork without exporting it as a non-vector.

Comment: @vpn I don't have much experience with it. Maybe I will look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft applications really *prefer* RGB files.

Customarily I save/export as a PNG24 at fairly large dimensions (wxh) for Word. Then reduce to desired size within Word.

You can try exporting a WMF, or even saving as an EPS from Illustrator. But in my experience, these formats all cause issues eventually even though Microsoft states they are supported formats. I would never really expect a PDF to be usable for Word.

Comment: So you use a width x height that would give you a PPI > 300?

Comment: And this does not answer all the questions in my post regarding the size of the actual document.

Comment: Okay .... what's this "Word template" for? That's not in the question. Word is not used for commercial printing. In fact many commercial printers will kickback Word files and not even accept them. I assumed the "word template" was for inner-office use, in which case... 300ppi is rarely necessary. 72/96/150 are all fine for general office use with office printers. If you intend to get things commercially printers... don't use Word. Word does not have features capable of supporting commercial printing.

Comment: "Currently the document is 512 x 512 points. However the logo is a rectangular shape, it is placed in the center. Should I create another document with the exact dimensions of the shape so there are no space on the sides before exporting?"

Comment: That can't really be answered.. remove space or don't. That's your call based on how you are using the art.

Comment: But in AI it doesn't bother me that there are space on the side. But when I export it I want only the rectangle.

Comment: Then either export just the art, or change the artboard to be the size you want exported.

Comment: In the "Save for web" there is an option that you can uncheck named "Clip to artboard". However isn't there a option like this on the new save menus?

Comment: If you are exporting/saving, you have to change the actual artboard size to the size you want to export.

Comment: In my experience, Word very often also has trouble with PNG24 if there's any transparency in it. JPEG or BMP(!) with a white background is he only format I've been able to get any kind of consistently acceptable result with, particularly if cross-platform consistency is required (especially an issue with PNGs—the same picture may work fine on a Mac, but then look seven kinds of screwed up when you open the file on a Windows machine).

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to get a letterhead into Word is to import it as a WMF file. It is vector, so it makes for small sizes and always prints clearly. There's some tricks to this approach though.

- First design it all in Illustrator, on an A4-sized page.
- Make sure all your artwork is in RGB
- Convert any text that you want to include to outlines (address + whatever you want to have as an image in Word)
- Put a white rectangle behind the whole letterhead, starting in the top left corner. Make sure it's the full page width (21cm) and as many cm as you need to surround all your items.
- Delete any other items on the page.
- Select all. Scale 500%. Artboard size doesn't matter.
- File › Export As… Then select Windows Metafile (WMF)

Then in Word:

- Drag the .wmf file into Word header.
- Use the menu Format › Format Picture › Size. Set Scale to 20%
- Format Picture › Layout. Set it to Behind text.
- Format Picture › Layout › Advanced. Position it 0 from Right of Page and 0 from Top of Page

Although that's a few steps in Word, it comes out perfectly without having to fidget with placement in Word. And if you need to update your header, it's easy to replace.

Now: why the 500% scale? Because the WMF file format is horrible. It will break bezier curves up into small, straight sections. But by enlarging it, and then reducing to 20% in Word, these aberrations become practically invisible, especially when printing.

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but Word supports SVG files now. Use them whenever possible.

Comment: An exact version number would be useful.

Comment: If you have an Office 365 subscription, you’re golden. I believe it started a few years ago: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c, so I’m not sure the actual version it happened.

Comment: Yeah, looks like 2018. One other note: we’ve had bad luck pasting SVGs into Word. Place the file and things seem to work fine.